# Regex: Full matching for a string split by delimiter

Tags: java, mysql, sql, regex

I am having a string which has a delimiter like "|"

```
e.g. "South NY, US | South-East NY, US| North NY, US"
```

note: the space around the pipe on either side may or may not appear.

I have been trying to use .contains() to match a given string, but it also match the case like "East NY, US"

I have got a small function (in java) to match a search string, but it is inefficient.

```
boolean fullmatch (String search, String text) {
    String[] split = text.split ("\\|");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
         if (split[i].trim().equals (search)) {
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What would be the equivalent regex for this? Thanks you

additional: What would be the equivalent regex in SQL too? (trying not to pull out large amount of data for comparison in Java)

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that your method is too inefficient, or that you can make it much more efficient; but for cleaner and simpler code (which also will perform at least somewhat better), you can write:

```
boolean fullmatch (String search, String text) {
    return Pattern.compile(
        "(?:^|\\|)\\s*" + Pattern.quote(search) + "\\s*(?:\\||$)")
        .matcher(text).find();
}
```

For example, if your `search` is `"South-East NY, US"`, then the above will return true if `text` contains a substring matching `(?:^|\|)\s*South-East NY, US\s*(?:\||$)` (start-of-string-or-pipe, plus optional whitespace, plus the search-string, plus optional whitespace, plus pipe-or-end-of-string).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean fullmatch (String search, String text) {
    return text.matches(".*(^|\\|)\\s*" + search + "\\s*(\\||$).*");
}
```

Comment: This will not be very efficient since `matches` will have to iterate over entire text, even if it will find correct element at start of it.

Comment: @Pshemo I suppose you mean mean efficient. Point accepted.